# How to make unordered list responsive on mobile view?

Tags: html, css

I want the links email, LinkedIn and GitHub to be responsive by having it directly at the bottom of the title let's connect when in mobile view. Also I would like the margin top of 200px to be none when in mobile view. Apologies for the newbie question.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  footer.content-container {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.footer-text {
  padding: 200px 100px;
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  line-height: 80px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-contact {
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #222222;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.footer-text-color {
  color: #222222;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 200px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<footer class="content-container footer">

  <div class="footer-text">Let's <br> <span class="footer-text-color">Connect</span></div>

  <ul>

    <li><a href=about.html class="footer-contact">Email</a></li>
    <li><a href=projects.html class="footer-contact">LinkedIn</a></li>
    <li><a href=contact.html class="footer-contact">GitHub</a></li>
  </ul>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 845px) {
  .footer-text {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    float: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
        footer.content-container {
          margin-left: 10px;
          margin-right: 10px;
        }
      }

      .footer {
        grid-area: footer;
        margin-top: 38px;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        height: 700px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
      }

      .footer-text {
        padding: 200px 100px;
        font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 80px;
        color: #bbbbbb;
        line-height: 80px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .footer-contact {
        font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: #222222;
        line-height: 50px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 60px;
        margin-right: 60px;
      }

      .footer-text-color {
        color: #222222;
      }

      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-top: 200px;
        float: right;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 845px) {
        .footer-text {
          padding-bottom: 0;
        }
        ul {
          margin-top: 0;
          float: unset;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <footer class="content-container footer">
      <div class="footer-text">
        Let's <br />
        <span class="footer-text-color">Connect</span>
      </div>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html" class="footer-contact">Email</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html" class="footer-contact">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" class="footer-contact">GitHub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @seantsang94121 Why does It only work when the media query is placed as the bottom of the css file instead of the top? Thanks

Comment: Generally the last rule takes precedence. With that being said, there are "exceptions" in that inline styles take precedence over external stylesheets ( an inline !important is more important than an external !important, etc ), and more specific selectors override generic selectors.
Read all about it @ http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

Comment: simply words: If you place my "media query code" as the top of the css file, the change to ```.footer-text``` and ```ul``` will be overrided because the last rule takes precedence.